# syntax_error:update for dictionary

Tags: python, string, dictionary

How can I fix this?

```
# E.g. word_count("I am that I am") gets back a dictionary like:
# {'i': 2, 'am': 2, 'that': 1}
# Lowercase the string to make it easier.
# Using .split() on the sentence will give you a list of words.
# In a for loop of that list, you'll have a word that you can
# check for inclusion in the dict (with "if word in dict"-style syntax).
# Or add it to the dict with something like word_dict[word] = 1.
def word_count(string):
    word_list = string.split()
    word_dict = {}
    for word in word_list:
        if word in word_dict:
            word_dict.update(word:word_dict(word)+1)
        else:
            word_dict[word]=1
    return word_dict
```

[image]

Disclaimer: A total newbie in Python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update a key in a dictionary, just assign to the key using `[...]` subscription syntax:

```
word_dict[word] = word_dict[word] + 1
```

or even

```
word_dict[word] += 1
```

Your attempt is not valid syntax, for two reasons:

- `word_dict.update()` is a method call, everything inside the `(...)` call syntax must be a valid expression. `key: value` is not a stand-alone expression, that only is valid within a `{key: value}` dictionary display. `word_dict.update()` takes either a dictionary object, or a sequence of `(key, value)` pairs.
- `word_dict(word)` would try to *call* the dictionary rather than try to retrieve the value for the key `word`.

Using `word_dict.update()` to update just *one* key is a little overkill, because it requires creating another dictionary or sequence. Either one of the following would work:

```
word_dict.update({word: word_dict[word] + 1})
```

or

```
word_dict.update([(word, word_dict[word] + 1)])
```

Note that the Python standard library comes with a better solution for counting words: the [`collections.Counter()` class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

def word_count(string):
    return Counter(string.split())
```

A `Counter()` is a subclass of `dict`.

Comment: how would I write that line using .update()? thanks for the answer :)

Comment: if interviewees use `from collections import Counter

def word_count(string):
    return Counter(string.split())` is that acceptable? What is the level of language use that is acceptable in an interview? Thanks for the tips

Comment: @MonaJalal: I'd say it demonstrates a level of familiarity with the standard library. I'd also further probe if they know about all the features of `Counter()`, ask what else could be done with it perhaps, or ask to demonstrate to me how to do the same thing without a `Counter()` to probe basic Python knowledge. It all depends on the position for which you are interviewing.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement using `dict.update`. Here is an example for `dict.update`

```
In [74]: test_dict = {1:'apple',2:'grapes'}
In [75]: test_dict.update({3:'orange'})
In [76]: test_dict
Out[76]: {1: 'apple', 2: 'test', 3: 'orange'}
```

For your problem change your code like this `word_dict.update(word:word_dict(word)+1)` **to** `word_dict.update({word:word_dict(word)+1})` .

Here is a [reference](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_update.htm).